# return unconstrained array in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, vivado, ghdl

what's the best way to return an unconstrained vector in vhdl?

```
function func(selector : natural) return std_logic_vector is
begin
    case selector is
        when 3 => return std_logic_vector("11");
        when 4 => return std_logic_vector("101");
        when others => return std_logic_vector("0");
    end case;
end function;
```

In this case i get string literal cannot be a type conversion operand, so it doesn't work. The signal selector is generic, so it don't have to be synthesizeable.

Comment: You have syntax errors after numeric literals 3 and 4. Do you mean to use a qualified expression which explicitly specifies a type? Qualified expressions:  `std_logic_vector'("11")`, `std_logic_vector'("101");` and `std_logic_vector'("0")`. The error message you haven't shown would tell you that you can't type convert a string to std_logic_vector, their element types aren't the same (character and std_ulogic) . Those ':'s should be "=>".

Comment: The : instead of <= was a mistake in here, i typed this part new for stackexchange, without unnecessary code. In the original code there're also "<=". However, it works with the ' you mentioned before the brackets.Thanks a lot. Can you give me a hint about how's this ' function called in this case?
Copy this in an answer, i'll mark as accepted!

Comment: Then edit your question...

Comment: You still don't have a viable code snippet in your question. You should be using right arrow  `=>` for associating a choice with the following return statement. `when 3 => return std_logic_vector'("11");`, etc. Please supply a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Include a complete error message. Your question is not useful as it stands. Note that the return value type is `std_logic_vector` and can provide the type of the string literals without the qualified expressions as Matthew Taylor commented to his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. The return value from your function will need to be associated with something when it is called and that something will have to be of a fixed width. In other words, you'll have to say thing like:

```
s <= func(n);
```

and `s` will have a fixed width, so all the return values from your function will have to have the same width.

Comment: My function return value is used in a generic map with an unconstrained array type. Like generic map(func(n)). The width of the generic is evaluated in lower hierarchy levels.

Comment: @FranzForstmayr In which case, I don't understand what you're asking. You can just say this `when 3 => return "11";`.

Comment: Ok, i didn't knew that this is possible. I saw, i just thought much too complicated!

Comment: *"The return value from your function will need to be associated with something when it is called and that something will have to be of a fixed width."* No, the return value must be ***evaluated***, as it would be in the OP's intended use as an initial value for a (generic) constant where the subtype indication does not supply a constraint. His MCVe could also provide usage for `func`.